# Number of passwords of length N with specific constraints

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, logic, combinatorics

Consider the set of 26 alphabet and 10 digits.

Write a function which returns the numbers of passwords of length N containing at-least L lowercase letters, at-least U uppercase letters and at-least D digits.

Function Signature **int cntPass(int N,int L,int U,int D)**

My approach:

I was trying to use recursion to solve it but I think its wrong.My (wrong) recurrence was as follows:

f(N,L,U,D)=f(N,L-1,U,D)+f(N,L,U-1,D)+f(N,L,U,D-1) [with the necessary base conditions but it didnt work].

I am looking for a better approach or a different logic to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is quite good, but you should change N for N-1 in your recursion I think and count the possibilities: f(N,L,U,D) = 26*f(N-1,L-1,U,D) + 26*f(N-1,L,U-1,D) + 10*f(N-1,L,U,D-1): if you fix the first character, you have N-1 left to fix. Moreover, you have 26 way of taking a lower case and so on. However, you should still use @nhahtdh's answer, since it does not use recursion.

Comment: @Dr_Sam Dont you think recursion with a bit of tweaking is the best way out? nhahtdh answer is not convincing enough.It couldn't account for the combination factors?Please reply.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how your recursion logic accounts for the **at least** part. I think nhahtdh's answer is good, why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @IVlad Yeah...It works now,I could not think of anything else but recursion :(

Comment: @Atanu I made the recursion. Even if you already accepted the other answer (which I up-voted), it might be worth a look.

Comment: @IVlad Take a look at my code. The at least part is taken into account be checking the values of the variables and the number of non-constrained characters left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a simple combinatorics problem. The result is <sup>N</sup>C<sub>L</sub> * <sup>N-L</sup>C<sub>U</sub> * <sup>N-L-U</sup>C<sub>D</sub> * 26<sup>L</sup> * 26<sup>U</sup> * 10<sup>D</sup> * 62<sup>N - U - L - D</sup>, which can be simplified a bit to 26<sup>L + U</sup> * 10<sup>D</sup> * 62<sup>N - U - L - D</sup> * N! / ( U! * L! * D! * (N - L - U - D)! ).

We choose L places for the lower case characters among N places. Then choose U places for upper case letters among the rest N - L places. And choose D places for digits among the rest N - L - U places. The rest are anything goes.

L lower case letters have 26 choices each. Same for U upper case letters. D digits have 10 choices each. For the rest (N - L - U - D), we can use any of 26 + 26 + 10 characters for each of them.

Comment: But will it not fail in certain cases? Like f(2,1,0,0)..Your answer will return 26*62.But shouldn't the answer be (26*62+62*26).Please clarify this doubt.Thanks

Comment: Yup you don't need to worry about that case.Its always valid.

Comment: Yup! so please edit the answer with the necessary changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @nhahtdh is fully correct. However, if large number are needed, it might be a bit tricky to compute the combinatorial factors (see the comments for a good way to do that).

Here is a way to compute the same numbers without passing by factorials, but with the recursion: Instead of considering, the function as int cntPass(int N,int L,int U,int D), add a last argument, which represents the number of digits that can be any of the 3:

int cntPass(int N,int L,int U,int D, int A)

Remark that we have A = N-L-U-D.
Now, the recursion is based on the choice of the first character: we have 26 choice for the lower case, 26 for the upper case and 10 for the digits.

Now, given N, L, U, D and A, one can

- put a lower case as first character -> 26 possibilities. For each of these possibilities, we have cntPass(N-1,L-1,U,D,A) possibilities for the rest of the password. Remark that if L=0, this does not work, **unless** A>0, i.e. there are still some characters free of choice. In this case, we also have 26 possibilities with cntPass(N-1,L,U,D,A-1) for each of them.
- Idem for upper case
- Idem for digits.

To end the recursion, we can either set the number of possibilities when N=1, or equivalently set the number when N=0 (to a symbolic 1).

Here is a Matlab code (used Matlab for quick testing) that makes it:

```
function [number]=Nword(N,LowerCase,UpperCase,Digit,Any)
number = 0;
if ( LowerCase > 0)
   number = number + 26*Nword( N-1, LowerCase-1, UpperCase, Digit, Any);
elseif (Any > 0)
    number = number + 26*Nword( N-1, LowerCase, UpperCase, Digit, Any-1);
end

if ( UpperCase > 0)
   number = number + 26*Nword( N-1, LowerCase, UpperCase-1, Digit, Any);
elseif( Any > 0)
    number = number + 26*Nword( N-1, LowerCase, UpperCase, Digit, Any-1);
end

if ( Digit > 0)
   number = number + 10*Nword( N-1, LowerCase, UpperCase, Digit-1, Any);
elseif( Any > 0)
    number = number + 10*Nword( N-1, LowerCase, UpperCase, Digit, Any-1);
end

if (number == 0)
   number = 1; 
end

return
```

Comment: The big factorial can be divided on the fly as we multiply. The maximum value in the calculation won't be too far away from the actual value.

Comment: Could you be more precise? I don't see how you can take into account for all the simplications while computing the multinomial factor.

Comment: For example (I go backward from n for clarity): n * (n - 1) / 2 * (n - 2) / 3 ... * (n - L + 1) / L * (n - L) * (n - L - 1) / 2 ... I use the fact that n consecutive number is divisible to n!

Comment: Umhh, I never thought about "picking one factor up and one factor down". Very interesting! The only tricky part is to be sure that you can perform all the divisions with integers, but your reasoning give the proof that you can do it. +1, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dr_Sam Please don't mind about that up-vote. I appreciate this answer a lot.This is how I looked at it first.I hope you did not down-vote my Question due to that.Thanks everyone for you help and answers.

Comment: @Atanu I was surprised that you accept the other answer without waiting for mine, but no problem, I did not down vote your question :-) I think however that you should accept nhahtdh's answer since it's the most efficient of the two answers!

Comment: @Dr_Sam I didn't know you were coming up with this awesome recursive soln; which i struggled to come up with after spending more than 4 hrs on it.Thanks.So with your permission I am accepting his answer :)